# Why is Nuget trying to access my SVN files?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget

I'm trying to update the Nuget packages in a solution I have, but this is what it does for all of them when I try to update

```
Successfully installed 'knockoutjs 2.2.1'.  
Updating 'knockoutjs' from version '2.2.0' to '2.2.1' in project 'MyProject'.  
Directory 'Scripts\.svn\text-base' is not empty. Skipping...  
Directory 'Scripts\.svn' is not empty. Skipping...  
Successfully removed 'knockoutjs 2.2.0' from MyProject.  
Successfully added 'knockoutjs 2.2.1' to MyProject.  
Access to the path '(solution path)\packages\knockoutjs.2.2.0\Content\Scripts\.svn\text-base\knockout-2.2.0.debug.js.svn-base' is denied.  
Access to the path '(solution path)\packages\knockoutjs.2.2.0\Content\Scripts\.svn\text-base\knockout-2.2.0.js.svn-base' is denied.  
Access to the path '(solution path)\packages\knockoutjs.2.2.0\Content\Scripts\.svn\all-wcprops' is denied.  
Access to the path '(solution path)\packages\knockoutjs.2.2.0\Content\Scripts\.svn\dir-prop-base' is denied.  
...
```

It pretty much does that for every SVN file. Then says it wasn't properly uninstalled and I need to restart Visual Studio for the changes to take effect, but that doesn't solve anything. I have to manually clear out the files and remove the `.deleteme` file that gets created.

I also tried running Visual Studio 2012 as Administrator but that didn't change anything. I also have full permissions on my Windows 7 machine to the entire project.

I thought `.svn` folders were supposed to be ignored by Nuget? Is it trying to delete the older package folder? I'm fine with it taking out all the content files, as long as it leaves the .svn folder alone. I can always mark the files as deleted on the next commit.

Also, I know I can run Nuget without commiting the packages to source control, but I don't want to do that. The feature isn't enabled and the checkbox that lets Nuget download missing packages is not checked. So if it thinks that source control integration is disabled I don't know why.

Comment: I have the exact same problem, did you ever get to the bottom of this one?

Comment: @PhilJenkins, unfortunately not. At that point Nuget was more of a hassle than a benefit so I just stopped using it for that specific project.